# What is the exact place for the definite article in the following sentence?

Tags: word-order

Which sentence is correct?

I could not find "Les Misérables" among **all the books**.

I could not find "Les Misérables" among **the all books**.

I am confused about the correct place of "the" in the above sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the first one: I could not find "Les Misérables" among all the books.

Comment: This would be improved if you said _why_ this option is correct.